# Delphi: MAPI with Zimbra client failed

Tags: delphi, email, client, mapi, zimbra

In a customer site they want to use Zimbra Mail client.
We use Delphi6 to develop.

Most of our customers can use the MAPI calls we provide from our application.
(There are some exceptions because of new OS-s, or exotic email clients).

Now we got problem with Zimbra Client.

The "Sender", "Recipients", "Subject" are lost, only the attachment appear (with miscoded utf8 characters).

The Excel, Word, and the Explorer can send documents.
When I send with Total Commander, or use XNView with MAPI, or Foxit PDF reader - I also got problem (Thunderbird shown the file name in subject on send, Zimbra no).

First I thought that caused by non-unicode MAPI. But as I read there is no unicoded MAPI call. Only UTF8 allowed - but when I used non problematic characters, like "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", this doesn't affect.

So may you have an idea what to do, or you also use Zimbra client with positive or negative experiences.

Let me know!

Thanks:
   dd

---

Extending with additional information:

1.) 
I use SendMail.pas (TSMMAPIMail) for sending.

2.)
Other programs (that working with Thunderbird) MAPI calling also failed, like XNView, Total Commander's local menu (Send).

---

Sorry, but I don't understand the source code, and I have no time to search and understand the implementation. 
Maybe it is don't containing code to get "to", "from", "subject", "body" fields.
I nevertheless trying with any application to call Zimbra Client, and pass these fields.
If some of the applications are working, they can pass only the attachment, and that's all.

I want an answer only that CAN I send MAPI fields and attachment with Zimbra too, or cannot do that...

I searched for any dotnet, or other examples that have compilable version, and with I can send through mapi (to I can see the "New Mail" with fields).
But I don't found any of them.

Is there anybody who can send with Zimbra through MAPI - and he/she can see the fields?

Here is SendMail.pas:
http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidE6AFD0AC14BFAEE91223DFB7BC0E2A57A5225A8A.aspx?s=delphi

If I use this, I can send the attachment - but fields are also lost.

Comment: Please show some actual code you're using to access the MAPI.

Comment: Have you contacted Zimbra Inc.? http://www.zimbra.com/support/

Comment: Hi! Because this is not my own Zimbra program, I don't have licence to contact the company. But I wrote to them into the forum: http://www.zimbra.com/forums/error-reports/53780-zimbra-client-mapi-anomalies.html#post232227 without any good answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Building_Zimbra_using_Perforce Maybe you can find the error in zimbras MAPI implementation and find a workaround.

Comment: The source code is also available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zimbracommunity/files/Source/FOSS-Releases/6.x/6.0.7/

Comment: This is the SendMail.pas code: http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidE6AFD0AC14BFAEE91223DFB7BC0E2A57A5225A8A.aspx?s=delphi

Answer (score 0):

for MAPI support in Zimbra, use Habitech Zimbra Notifier. It has a trial version to test. 
[Zimbra Notifier with MAPI support](http://www.habitech.com.ar/productos/producto.php?id=18)